# Creating a custom button in Jodit Editor

Tags: jodit

I'm trying to create a custom table button using Jodit React Editor using this as reference - https://xdsoft.net/jodit/examples/toolbar/custom_button.html
I'm a little lost on this though. 
I need to be able to create a table and have the icon be a text icon that says - "Table"

Right now I've added this to my configurations - extraButtons: ['tableNew'].

I've also added the below code to the render method.

```
this.jodit.options.controls.tableNew = {
  iconURL: '',
  exec: function (editor) {
      return '<table> <thead>   <tr>  <th> Sl no </th> <th>Name</th> <th>Age</th>   </tr> </thead>'+
      ' <tbody>   <tr> <td>1</td> <td></td> <td></td>   </tr>  </tbody>  </table>';
  }
};
```

I see that a space has been added in the toolbar which on hover says tableNew but on clicking it nothing happens.
I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the following,

```
return '<table> <thead>   <tr>  <th> Sl no </th> <th>Name</th> <th>Age</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody>   <tr> <td>1</td> <td></td> <td></td>   </tr>  </tbody> </table>';
```

try something like this:

```
return editor.create.fromHTML('<table> <thead>   <tr>  <th> Sl no </th> <th>Name</th> <th>Age</th>   </tr> </thead> <tbody>   <tr> <td>1</td> <td></td> <td></td>   </tr>  </tbody>  </table>');
```

This works for me (a similiar implementation, not returning table like you, but return some list).

Comment: What are you exactly doing to add a custom button that insert html text into the editor.  I can create the button but when I click on it, nothing happens with the example given above... no error. Following another exampple at https://xdsoft.net/jodit/v.2/doc/tutorial-how-create-module.html, I get a js error saying that the jodit.dummy is undefined.

Comment: @PaulGodard Here is code snippet [link](https://hastebin.com/cowazimepe.js) which could help. I am using this snippet to creating my custom buttons for Jodit editor, hopefully it will helps.